# How to place a form field input directly into php array within form

Tags: php, arrays, forms, input, field

I am developing an application where photographs can be ordered online. I am using a form with php to input the number of copies required of a photo. I want to accept the input from the form into a php array directly into the form. So far I am unable to get the input into the array. Can anyone please help. The code for this is below.

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='photoid' size='14' class='required' value='$photoid' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='galleryname' size='10' class='required' value='$galleryname' />";
$index = $option['id'];
echo "<td><input type='number' name='$photoorder[$index]' size='1' placeholder='0' autocomplete='off' />"
```

In the above $photoorder is the array and [$index] is for the array position. `$index = $option[id]` just obtains the array position where the data is to be entered.

Comment: Try to: print_r('$option'); and same with $index, Then post the results in your question.

Comment: Can you post the output HTML you're getting?

Comment: The output from print_r on $index gives the numeric value fro the position within the array where the data is to go.

Comment: The output from print_r on $option  gives the full listing from the table I am using to hold photo prices.